# Change default Toolbar-Button Hover Template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, themes

How to change the default Hover-Template (and the Selected-Template of a ToggleButton)?

[image: Brush]

As you can see, i create a dark-themed Application. This blue colored hover-effect does not fit in my theme. so i need to know how to change this default behaviour. Which ControlTemplate is responsible for this and how can i override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This official MSDN documentation has the answer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970772(v=vs.100).aspx